# Issue while connecting Graylog server to Elastic Search

Tags: exception, elasticsearch, connection, graylog2, graylog

Hi my configurations are:

elasticsearch.yml :

```
cluster.name: graylog2
node.master: true
node.data: true
bootstrap.mlockall: true
ES_HEAP_SIZE: 8192 (@ 16GB memory)
network.bind_host: 127.0.0.1
script.disable_dynamic: true
```

graylog2.conf :

```
is_master = true
node_id_file = /etc/graylog2-server-node-id
password_secret=something
root_password_sha2=something
plugin_dir = plugin
rest_listen_uri = http://127.0.0.1:12900/
rest_transport_uri = http://127.0.0.1:12900/
elasticsearch_shards = 1
elasticsearch_index_prefix = graylog2
elasticsearch_cluster_name = graylog2
elasticsearch_discovery_zen_ping_multicast_enabled = false
elasticsearch_discovery_zen_ping_unicast_hosts = 127.0.0.1:9300
```

I am trying to install in my apache localhost.

When I check using curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_cluster/health?pretty=true'

The output I get is :

```
 {
  "cluster_name" : "graylog2",
  "status" : "green",
  "timed_out" : false,
  "number_of_nodes" : 1,
  "number_of_data_nodes" : 1,
  "active_primary_shards" : 0,
  "active_shards" : 0,
  "relocating_shards" : 0,
  "initializing_shards" : 0,
  "unassigned_shards" : 0
}
```

I have followed the tutorial https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-graylog2-and-centralize-logs-on-ubuntu-14-04

OUTPUT:
2016-01-18 18:45:53,221 WARN : org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen - [graylog2-server] failed to connect to master [[Sunpyre][l1hOltklR-OIeBq7dcPR9g][inet[/172.16.1.169:9300]]{master=true}], retrying...
org.elasticsearch.transport.ConnectTransportException: [Sunpyre][inet[/172.16.1.169:9300]] connect_timeout[30s]

2016-01-18 18:45:53,221 WARN : org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen - [graylog2-server] failed to connect to master [[Sunpyre][l1hOltklR-OIeBq7dcPR9g][inet[/172.16.1.169:9300]]{master=true}], retrying...
org.elasticsearch.transport.ConnectTransportException: [Sunpyre][inet[/172.16.1.169:9300]] connect_timeout[30s]

**ERROR: Could not successfully connect to ElasticSearch. Check that your cluster state is not RED and that ElasticSearch is running properly.**

Comment: I am relatively new to elastic search and graylog.Any help will be appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

with official documentation I haven't problem

- http://docs.graylog.org/en/1.3/pages/installation.html
- http://docs.graylog.org/en/2.0/pages/installation.htm

please check Elasticsearch version